# Openshift asks to change permission of file to 600 on Windows

Tags: openshift

while executing rhc setup i got following error

> Your private SSH key file should be set as readable only to yourself. Please run CHMOD 600 C:/user/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa

Now how can i execute such command on windows. 
However, I tried to use git bash. But have not got any success.!!

Comment: `attrib +r <filename>` at a command prompt, or right-click the file in Explorer, choose Properties, and then check the Read only box. Either way, this is not a programming question, so it's off-topic here. Questions about use of the operating system belong on [su].

Comment: it's still saying that i should fire CHMOD 600 C:/user/mysuesr/.ssh/id_rsa. However, I followed your comment and now file's permission is r--r--r--.

Comment: @Jigar (or someone else) did you achieve to solve it? I'm having the same problem on Windows 8.1 x64 working with a Laravel 5.3 project + Passport 1.0, Laravel is requesting me to chmod 600 or 660 the file oauth-private.key (working on an API to allow loggin-in users from a mobile app)

Answer (score 1):

You can execute Linux commands on windows machine using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

There are a couple of more tools using which you can do the same but I found Cygwin great!!!